# Different Sidemenu in ionic 2 app

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I would like to have different side menus in ionic 2 app based on user login.
When a user logs in as customer , I want to show a side-menu with customer functionalities.
When a user logs in as admin, I will show different side-menu.

I am using Ionic 2 sidemenu template

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `*ngIf` on an element inside your sidebar to display based on if the user is logged in as admin.

Example:

`<div class="side-bar-admin" *ngIf="admin'"></div>`